# I want to create an S3 bucket that can only be accessed by users created with Cognito when they sign in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I want to be accessible in the following ways:

```
const cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
IdentityPoolId: "us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx,
Logins: {
  'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx': result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
}
});

// このようにアクセスしたい。
window.location.href = "https://nabezokodaikon-private.s3.amazonaws.com/private/index.html";
```

I have created the following S3 bucket policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::nabezokodaikon-private/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/nabezokodaikon"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::nabezokodaikon-private/index.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

But this is not accessible.
How can I do what I want?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Cognito, but that policy seems to be saying "Allow via Cognito but deny if not this User". Those are contradictory. Does it work if you remove the `Deny` portion?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I tried to delete Deny, but it remained inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

While your code is obtaining credentials from Cognito, this line is not supplying any information that identifies the request as coming from the Cognito credentials:

```
window.location.href = "https://nabezokodaikon-private.s3.amazonaws.com/private/index.html";
```

That URL is just a normal anonymous request, which should be rejected (as it is).

To gain access to the private content, you will need to create a **pre-signed URL** that uses the credentials supplied by Cognito to 'sign' the request. A pre-signed URL provides time-limited access to private content in Amazon S3.

See: [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

You will also need to remove the `Deny` statement, since it will block *any* access that doesn't come from the stated user. Amazon S3 buckets are private by default, so `Deny` should only be used in situations where an `Allow` needs to be overridden.

Comment: As you said, I was able to access. Thank you!
But how do you access CSS and JS files associated with HTML files?
With this method, only a single file can be accessed.

Comment: Also, it seems that you need an access key and secret key to achieve this.
I think these are things that I keep secret from my clients, but how do I do that?

Comment: Typically, an application generates the HTML pages and it inserts pre-signed URLs when the pages are requested. As an example, think of a photo sharing website. Photos are private, but the owner of the photos should be allowed to see their own photos. When the app generates an HTML page with links or `<img>` tags that refer to the photos, it creates pre-signed URLs for all those links. Generally, CSS and scripts are made public, so you would only generate pre-signed URL for files that need to be kept private.